# Cannot Add Programmatic Layout Constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a group of radio buttons with the library [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) and want the group to be centered, just off of the bottom edge of the ViewController.

I am trying to work with programmatic constraints so that I can ensure the radio group is rendered correctly on each device:

```
 var buttons = [DLRadioButton]()

    for x in 0..<self.numberOfChildren {
    let answerLabel = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childSnapshot(forPath: String(x+1)).childSnapshot(forPath: "answer").value
            let firstRadioButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: CGFloat(x)*32, width: 100.0, height: 120.0), title: answerLabel as! String, color: UIColor.green)
            firstRadioButton.tag = x
            buttons.append(firstRadioButton)
            self.view.addSubview(firstRadioButton);
        }

    let groupButtons = DLRadioButton()
    let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    **groupButtons.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true**
    groupButtons.otherButtons = buttons
    })
```

Comment: I think for the constraints to work, either `groupButtons` should be a subview of `self`, or both be subviews of the same parent...

Comment: How would I do that through code?

Comment: Hmm, `self.view.addSubview(groupButtons)`?

Comment: I tried and it removed the error, however now the constraint code doesn't appear to be doing anything. The radio buttons are not appearing where I had hoped.

Comment: Make sure the constrained subviews have all the constraints necessary to avoid ambiguity. Right now, you are only constraining the **bottom** anchor. Do the buttons have a fixed height? what about horizontal direction? Do they have a width? Leading margin to the superview?

Comment: got it, new to swift and constraints, when I initialize I firstRadioButton I believe I set these values

Comment: When you do autolayout on programmatically created subviews, make sure to set their `translatesAutoresizingMaskConstraints` property to `false`, otherwise you end up with multiple, redundant (or worse, contradictory) constraints for e.g. size. Interface Builder automatically does this for you so not needed for storyboard-based subviews.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144983/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-nicolas-miari).

Comment: I just did that, and now I do not see the buttons on the screen, do I have to set the width and height programmatically now?